# Spring MemCached flush all strange behaviour

Tags: java, spring-mvc, memcached, spymemcached, simple-spring-memcached

In a spring web project, if we are using a single cache server and different cache managers an eg annotation is

```
@Cacheable(value = "configCache", key="#key")
@Cacheable(value = "envCache", key="#key")
...
```

and if we do

```
@CacheEvict(value = "configCache", allEntries=true)
```

and if we have enabled `allowClear=true` in the configuration, so will this only evict the `configCache`? or it will clear `envCache` as well?

We have seen many flush_all commands being executed in Amazon ElasticCache and majority of the items gets reclaimed. So is this because we are using evict allEntries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If will also clear *envCache* if it's on the same memcached instance/server as *configCache*. 
Because memcached doesn't support namespaces only all keys can be removed from the instance.